# IE8 no honoring display:none

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following markup on a page and unfortunately I do not have direct access to it. . This page is opened in an iframe. There is other code on the page but it is not relevant so I have not posted it.

The only access to target the code in via css.

I want to not display the close button so I added this to the css file

```
img[alt='Close'] {display:none !important;}
```

this is the markup

```
<td align="center"><a href='javascript:window.close()'><img src='v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_close.gif' alt='Close' border=0></a></td>
```

It works as expected in all browsers that i have tested (firefox, Opera, Safari) but in IE8 it seems to ignore this css and shows the button. Not sure if it doesn't like the selector or perhaps I have a syntax error.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try `img[alt=Close]` (no quotes at all) or `img[alt="Close"]` (double quotes rather than single) on the off-chance, although frankly don't think it'll make a difference, all three (yours and those two) are valid. Still, it's IE, anything's possible.

Comment: Don't have IE8 here to test, but it is most probably the selector. IE up to version 9 still lags behind with CSS3 selectors support.

Comment: Thx, yeah I already tried several combos of the close and still no luck, but thx gotta luv MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 supports Attribute Selectors, but only when the page is setup for "standards-compliant mode". The following provides more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770069.aspx [Read the Remarks Section]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx

Also the following link tells you what DTD turns standards compliance mode "on" in IE8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242.aspx [Scroll to the table]

Comment: I see so it is a IE issue. and darn there is no doc deceleration on this page and I have no access to the markup to add the the strict doc type, like i said gotta luv MS

Comment: @user357034 you either need to change the markup, configure the web server to specify a default mode, or make changes to your register (this last option will only affect you, but other users will still see the non standards mode). The second document I linked to includes all the information about Document Compatibility Modes. Sorry the answer is not what you were hoping for :(

Comment: thx but the 1st is not possible as I do not have access to the markup since it is the output of an .asp page in an iframe. I have no access to the web server as this is a e-commerce site. The third quite frankly i have no idea what it is. Thx for the replies.

Comment: I meant the windows registry. I wouldn't recommend it though.